# Django cannot run tests when DATABASES 'default' is empty

Tags: python, django

I have some troubles running tests with setting `DATABASES['default'] = {}`.

I got the folowing error when running `./manage.py test`

```
$ ./manage.py test --failfast
Creating test database for alias 'mydb'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_admin (myapp.test.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 182, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 754, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 887, in _fixture_setup
    if not connections_support_transactions():
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 874, in connections_support_transactions
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 874, in <genexpr>
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 55, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 782, in supports_transactions
    self.connection.leave_transaction_management()
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 338, in leave_transaction_management
    if managed == self.get_autocommit():
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 345, in get_autocommit
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/tmpapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 86, in __exit__
    db_exc_type = getattr(self.wrapper.Database, dj_exc_type.__name__)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'mydb'...
```

**settings.py**

```
..
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'mydb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.router.MyRouter']
```

**router.py**

```
class MyRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'mydb'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'mydb'

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        if db == 'default':
            return False
        return True
```

**test.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase                                                                                                                                       


class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_admin(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

I did some investigation and find that `self.connect()` was called on the dummy backend associated with `'default'` alias. Since the dummy backend does not implement much fonctionnalities, the call fails. How can I run tests with `DATABASES['default'] = {}` ?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this, but I think using `'default': DATABASES["mydb"]` should make this work.

Comment: I dont want to set a default database. I am trying to build a multi-db app and I dont want to take the risk some data goes in a place I dont want to because the router did not manage to determine the right db.

Comment: I believe you could do some faking by adding `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'` to your DATABASE default setting.

Comment: This is the default when using `DATABASES['default'] = {}`

Comment: Django docs suggest this is allowed (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/, second example) but I get the same error the OP does.

Comment: Bug report for this problem: [Running tests fails when DATABASES…](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24394)

Comment: As other suggested its not test fault. Its Djano failing to initialize db related components.

Answer (score 0):

Use different settings.py files for production/development/testing (best).

And or use Sqlite as default entry (quickest).